# Dandelion Datatables tag dt inside fragment

Tags: java, thymeleaf

When I create a thymeleaf fragment, dandelion `dt` attribute do not read the thymeleaf variables.

I try to explain better with the code.

Fragment

```
<th:block layout:fragment="table">
        <div dt:conf="${tableId}">
            <div dt:confType="callback" dt:type="format" dt:function="formatNumberCallback"></div>
        </div>
        <table th:id="${tableId}"
               dt:table="true"
               dt:ext="responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th:block layout:fragment="table-header">Default table header</th:block>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <th:block layout:fragment="table-content">Default table content</th:block>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </th:block>
```

Page

```
<div layout:include="fragments/components/table :: table" th:with="tableId='usersTableTest'" th:remove="tag">
                Default
            </div>
```

Error:

```
08:48:31,825 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-5)        org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'com.github.dandelion.datatables.thymeleaf.processor.config.DivConfTypeAttrProcessor' (fragments/components/table:11)
08:48:31,825 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-5)    at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:225) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
08:48:31,826 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-5)    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
08:48:31,826 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-5)    at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
```

In this case `th:id="${tableId}` work correctly but `dt:conf="${tableId}"` not work.

Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to insert #vars as does the library **spring security thymeleaf**

```
dt:conf="#vars.tableId"
```

and **work well**.

Comment: I suppose I didn't understood you question correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a Dandelion Datatables's bug and it's not fixed.

Here is the issue in [Dandelion's repository in GitHub](https://github.com/dandelion/dandelion/issues/28).